# LIST VIEW in VB.net error

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem

```
Private Sub lvUnavailableProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvUnavailableProducts.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product_Suppliers WHERE ProductCode = '" & lvUnavailableProducts.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text & "'", conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If sdr.Read = True Then
        Fill("SELECT DISTINCT SupplierCode, SupplierName FROM Product_Suppliers  WHERE ProductCode ='" & lvUnavailableProducts.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text & "'", lvProductSupplier)
        conn.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("No added Supplier Yet, Please add a supplier")
        lvProductSupplier.Items.Clear()
        conn.Close()
    End If


End Sub
```

> I Am encountering an error when selected data on LvUnavailableProducts was changed
>
> Please Help Thank you :D

Comment: What error do you get and on which line(use debugger)?

Comment: Not the source of your error, but when you are encountering an error, you are not closing the database connection, which is very bad. You should be implementing the "using" statement to handle the closing of the sql connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.SelectedItems(0)` into `.FocusedItem`

```
lvUnavailableProducts.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text
```